# Error while testing the logging in to Google using the WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: google-apps-script, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I tried to configure Google as a service provider for WSO2 Identity Server, according the documentation (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/logging-in-to-google-using-the-identity-server/#configuring-google). But what was found was, after doing the complete setup, when executing the 2nd point of the 'Try it out' section, the url https://google.com/a/<ENTER_YOUR_DOMAIN>/acs returns a blank page where actually I should be redirected to a page where I need to enter my credentials (note: I didn't forget to replace the ENTER_YOUR_DOMAIN section).

It seems the document and the link is outdated. What link should I go to, to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following URL:

- https://admin.google.com/Dashboard
- https://admin.google.com/<domain.com>/Dashboard
- https://workspace.google.com/dashboard